# Why not popBackStack, popBackStackImmediate not working and changes behaviour?

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I am learning fragment and back stacks behavior.

I have 3 Fragments, I am adding this Fragment as `ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);`.

I have two senario:

**1)**. I am adding 3 fragments one by one as `add(id,fragment)` and also adding in  `ft.addToBackStack(tag);`.

And When i BackPress , It will be pop one by one by following code :

```
String fragmentTag = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
fm.popBackStack(fragmentTag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

In this scenario, it works fine.

**2)**. I am adding 3 fragments one by one as `add(id,fragment)` and here I only **adding 1st Fragment in  `ft.addToBackStack(tag);`**. **2nd and 3rd are not added to BackStack.**

And When i BackPress , Perform following code :

```
String fragmentTag = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
    fm.popBackStack(fragmentTag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

It will give **1st Fragment Tag**, however, Screen is not refreshing. It still shows the 3rd Fragment.

I also tried with `fm.popBackStackImmediate();` ,  `fm.popBackStack();`.

But the result is the same. Why Is It not happening?

Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: Because you do not add 2nd and 3d fragments to the stakList, `popBackStack` works only for fragments, which are in stackList. In scenario 2 your 1st fragment 
 is behind the the 3d fragment, which is not added to stackList. And `popBackStack` removes 1st fragment, but you do not see this, because 3d fragment visible

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai   ohh, that is very logical answer. Thank you.:) Actually, when i back press on Third Fragment, I want third fragment to First Fragment. So I didn't added 2nd and 3rd Fragment to backstack.